# Problem with Python class - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fd'

Tags: python, python-class, alpha-vantage

I have a problem with **creating a class correctly**. I wrote the code before without a class and there was no problem. But I need the code within a class, as the script is only part of a larger project. Unfortunately, I can't do it without errors.

The script should simply get the fundamental data of a company via the Alpha-Vantage API and store it on a certain variable.

```
import os
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.fundamentaldata import FundamentalData
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange


class DATA:
    def __init__(self, name, ticker):
        self.name = name
        self.ticker = ticker
    
    # Get Alpha Vantage Key
    api_key = os.getenv("ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY")

    # Define various Alpha Vantage classes
    ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format="pandas")
    fd = FundamentalData(key=api_key, output_format="pandas")
    fo = ForeignExchange(key=api_key, output_format="pandas")

    # Fundamental Data
    def fundamental(self, category="Name"):
        """
        help function to get fundamental data by category
        :param category: Alpha Vantage category name as string
        :return: selected fundamental data
        """
        fundamental_data = self.fd.get_company_overview(symbol=self.ticker)
        fun_data = fundamental_data[0]
        fun_data = fun_data[category].values[0]
        return fun_data


    exchange = fundamental("Exchange")
    currency = fundamental("Currency")
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/coding/stock-report/core/data.py", line 11, in <module>
    class DATA:
  File "/Users/coding/stock-report/core/data.py", line 37, in DATA
    exchange = fundamental("Exchange")
  File "/Users/coding/stock-report/core/data.py", line 31, in fundamental
    fundamental_data = self.fd.get_company_overview(symbol=self.ticker)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

Comment: Do you want `exchange` and `currency` to be (1) attributes of the `DATA` class, or (2) attributes of an instance of the `DATA` class, or (3) do you you want them to be variables outside the class scope?

Comment: You are calling `fundamental` as a regular function, not a method of the `DATA` class. As a result, the string `"Exchange"` (not a non-existent instance of `DATA`) is the first argument, which gets bound to the parameter `self`.

Comment: You need to create a class instance: `d = DATA("Apple", "AAPL")` Then call `d.fundamendal("Exchange")`

Comment: @mkrieger1 (3) Yes, I want them to be variables outside the class scope. I would then like to integrate this in a PDF

Comment: Then first of all those two lines need to be unindented one level.